# How to transform output from xml1 and xml2 according multiple conditions in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am quite new to XSLT and trying to learn it by myself. Anywhere, is it possible to display specific tag/node from XML1 by XSLT that transforms XML2 according where conditions are met?

To be concrete, I have XML1 (price list) containing each time node `<UP>` as unit price `<PID>` as product ID and `<Desc>` as description. (all three are mandatory). I need to display the `<UP>` in the appropriate line by my XSLT that transforms my XML2 (invoice), but only where `(<PID> and <Desc>)` are equal at the same time as product identification.

### XML1 - price list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<F19-priceList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <priceList>
        <odd>VK</odd>
        <typ>S</typ>
        <pid>175700</pid>
        <Desc>text 1</Desc>
        <UP>0.01</UP>
    </priceList>
    <priceList>
        <odd>VK</odd>
        <typ>E</typ>
        <pid>175700</pid>
        <Desc>text 2</Desc>
        <UP>0.02</UP>
    </priceList>
    <priceList>
        <odd>VK</odd>
        <typ>S</typ>
        <pid>200120</pid>
        <Desc>text 1</Desc>
        <UP>0.11</UP>
    </priceList>
    <priceList>
        <odd>VK</odd>
        <typ>E</typ>
        <pid>200120</pid>
        <Desc>text 3</Desc>
        <UP>0.13</UP>
    </priceList>
    <priceList>
        <odd>VK</odd>
        <typ>E</typ>
        <pid>200120</pid>
        <Desc>text 5</Desc>
        <UP>0.15</UP>
    </priceList>
</F19-priceList>
```

### XML2 - invoice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FA-data0 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Vendor1>
        <ODD>VK</ODD>
        <TYP>S</TYP>
        <PID>175700</PID>
        <Desc>text 1</Desc>
        <Amount>1000</Amount>
        <Unit>pcs</Unit>
        <VAT>20%</VAT>
    </Vendor1>
    <Vendor1>
        <ODD>VK</ODD>
        <TYP>S</TYP>
        <PID>200120</PID>
        <Desc>text 1</Desc>
        <Amount>1100</Amount>
        <Unit>pcs</Unit>
        <VAT>20%</VAT>
    </Vendor1>
    <Vendor1>
        <ODD>VK</ODD>
        <TYP>E</TYP>
        <PID>200120</PID>
        <Desc>text 5</Desc>
        <Amount>5500</Amount>
        <Unit>pcs</Unit>
        <VAT>20%</VAT>
    </Vendor1>
</FA-data0>
```

At this point, do I need to create a temporary XML file for the XSLT or can it be pulled in one transformation?

The result should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FA-data0 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Vendor1>
        <ODD>VK</ODD>
        <TYP>S</TYP>
        <PID>175700</PID>
        <Desc>text 1</Desc>
        <Amount>1000</Amount>
        <Unit>pcs</Unit>
        <UP>0.01</UP>
        <VAT>20%</VAT>
    </Vendor1>
    <Vendor1>
        <ODD>VK</ODD>
        <TYP>S</TYP>
        <PID>200120</PID>
        <Desc>text 1</Desc>
        <Amount>1100</Amount>
        <Unit>pcs</Unit>
        <UP>0.11</UP>
        <VAT>20%</VAT>
    </Vendor1>
    <Vendor1>
        <ODD>VK</ODD>
        <TYP>E</TYP>
        <PID>200120</PID>
        <Desc>text 5</Desc>
        <Amount>5500</Amount>
        <Unit>pcs</Unit>
        <UP>0.15</UP>
        <VAT>20%</VAT>
    </Vendor1>
</FA-data0>
```

This is my humble try.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>....</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="FA-data0/Vendor1">
      <xsl:variable name="plCmpr" select="document('priceList.xml')//priceList/pid | //priceList/Desc/"/>
      <xsl:variable name="invCmpr" select="document('invoice.xml')//Vendor1/PID | //Vendor1/Desc/"/>
        <xsl:if test="Amount &gt; 0">
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="ODD"/></td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="TYP"/></td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="PID"/></td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Desc"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Amount"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Unit"/></td>

          <!-- this is what I don't know -->
            <xsl:if test="$plCmpr &eq; $invCmpr">
              <td><xsl:value-of select="document('priceList.xml')//priceList/UP"/></td>
            </xsl:if>

          <!-- the following lines works only if UP is already set in XML2 - obviously 
          <td><xsl:value-of select="UP"/></td>
          -->

          <td><xsl:value-of select="VAT"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(UP*Amount,'###.00')"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(UP*Amount*0.2,'###.00')"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(UP*Amount*1.2,'###.00')"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know it is a way off.

Comment: Where do you "learn" stuff like `$plCmpr &eq; $invCmpr`? You might want to start with a book like https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm or any other XPath and XSLT tutorial.

Comment: You appear to be building an HTML output and not the desired XML you show.

Comment: Hi, yes, I have to display it as HTML. I just need to read out from those two. I just wanted to show, what I need to achieve. It should look as if it would be the result XML. Problem is, to display the appropriate UP from priceList related to actual product on invoice.

Comment: If you want an HTML result, then edit your question and show the HTML result you expected to get from the given example.

Answer (score 0):

If you tell your application to process the `invoice.xml` document and supply the path to the `priceList.xml` document as a parameter, you can get the expected output (or one very similar to it) using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-pricelist">priceList.xml</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/FA-data0">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Vendor1">
            <xsl:variable name="productID" select="PID" />
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="document($path-to-pricelist)/F19-priceList/priceList[pid=current()/PID and Desc=current()/Desc]/UP" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this can be made more elegant in XSLT 2.0 by using a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I was thinking about the "key" right now :)

Comment: Anyway, the priceList.xml can change from time to time. I just need to read out from this two XML files (is a temporary file required, where I would copy the UP?)  and display the result as HTML (by XSLT).

Comment: The price list can change - and the transformation will fetch the prices that are current at runtime. I don't see why you would need a temporary file. But if you want an HTML result, you need to tell the XSLT stylesheet to produce an HTML file.